# Multiple instances of the same Active Form

Tags: c++builder

I have an Active Form, I made some years ago, compiled as an ocx. It is installed on the tool palette.

I've only used one instance of it on each main application, and it has worked fine.

Now I need to use many instances of this active form from the same main application. So I drop a couple of them from the tool palette to my main application. But no matter which of the active forms I use (it has an built in form I open) from the application, the same instance of it shows up. And this is not what I want.

I can't figure out if the active form should been created in a different way, or if I should use it different from the main application.

The active form is built with c++builder XE, and the main application is built with XE6.

This is the way I create the instances:

```cpp
 __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
   : TForm(Owner)
{
   ActXList = new TList;

   TMyActX *TempActX;

   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      TempActX = new TMyActX(Owner);
      TempActX->Parent = this;  //Tried also with NULL and a new TForm(this), same result 
      ActXList->Add(TempActX);
      TempActX->Init(i);  //This adds i to a string in the created instance
   }

   MyActX1->Init(20);    //Adds 20 to a string in the design time created instance
   MyActX2->Init(21);    //Adds 21 to a string in the instance
}
```

And here I open the different instances:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   TMyActX *TempActX;

   //A Combobox chooses the instance to show
   if(ComboBox1->ItemIndex < 10)
   {
      TempActX = (TMyActX *)ActXList->Items[ComboBox1->ItemIndex];
      TempActX->ShowForm();
   }
   else if(ComboBoxTerminaler->ItemIndex == 10)
      MyActX1->ShowForm();
   else if(ComboBoxTerminaler->ItemIndex == 11)
      MyActX2->ShowForm();

   //No matter which instance is chosen to be shown, 
   //the label with the init-string shows "0 1 2 3...9 20 21" for all of them
}
```

For testing, the integer i is added to an Label in ->Init(). TMyActX has an internal form where the Label is shown. If I open this from (with any of the created instances), the Label shows "0 1 2 3 4...". Therefore I make the conclusion that ->Init() calls the same instance, and the same form is opened no matter which created instance I use to open it.

The same thing happens if I drop two instances to my main form at design time. The same Label is shown if I open the ocx-form.

The reason I use an ocx, is that the ocx is a part of a payment solution, that is certified by a external organization. So I don't want to not mess around with it, if possible. But I have access of the code for it, and for testing I can change it.

Comment: Please show how you are using the OCX ActiveForm in your VCL code. Maybe you are just not accessing it correctly. How do you know the same instance shows up each time? What are you using to differentiate them?

Comment: Do you have access to change the source code of the OCX? It might make sense to extract the OCX's UI into a reusable `TFrame` that you can then use in multiple projects, then you don't need the OCX in your VCL project.

Comment: I've added code and info in the post.

Comment: You said you drop ActiveForms onto your MainForm at design-time, but you have shown code that creates the ActiveForms dynamically instead. You are not accessing the design-time instances at all.  Also, when creating them dynamically, you should be using `this` as the Owner, not the MainForm's own `Owner`. And you are not setting the ActiveForm's `Parent` at all.

Comment: I've adjusted the code above so it is more ovious how I tried both design time and dynamically created instances, I hope it is clearer now.

I've tried both `this` and `Owner` when creating them dynamically, same result.

True, I did not set Parent. Now I've tried with `this`, `NULL` and to create a `new TForm`. Same result. 

In http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Parent, it says that that Parent is NULL for ActiveX Controls. I'm not sure how to read that.

Comment: `*TempActX = ...` will not compile, needs to be `TempActX = ...` instead

Comment: Of course. Adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

if you got access to the `TForm` class of your form then just create new instances on runtime like:

```
TForm *win[10];
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) win[i]=new TForm(this);
```

where `this` is pointer to parent **VCL** form created by IDE. This works for me but I do not use ocx instead I include the 3 files per window `(*.h,*.cpp,*.dfm)` however I am bound to BDS2006 so on newer versions of builder things may be a bit different ...

Do not forget that to make this work you can not have global variables in your form, and have proper close/destroy method of the `win[]` on apps close.

You can access your windows by their pointer (to show or hide them or whatever) also you should handle the manual close of window (so you do not access dead pointer latter on)

Comment: I will play around with this when I get back to office after the weekend.